# css selector for input type text

Tags: html, css, selenium, css-selectors

I have the following input:

[image]

I want to learn how to create a CSS selector to find it. First I use what Chrome Developer Tools give to me (as a starting point). It is `#deviceHeaderContainer > div > form > div > input`.

Everything is OK, it finds the element, but when I'm trying to use some more general selector like `input[type=text]`, then I get null as response, see the image below:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You just add screenshots, you need to share your code and what you already try here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should remove space between input and [type=text]
Should be `document.querySelector("input[type=text]")`

Answer (score 0):

it should be `input[type="text"]` , remove the space. Your selector means find `input` where child has a property `[type="text"]`, `input[type="text"]` `input [type="text"]` is different

Answer (score 0):

It's a simple fix. Remove the space between `input` and `[type="text"]`. It will look like this:

```
input[type="text"]
```